# TypeError in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeerror

I have some JavaScript code:

```
var update_money = function(money_am){
    var d = {'ammount': money_am};
    $.post("/adr/", d, load_money)
}

z = parseFloat($('#money').val());
$('#money').change(z, update_money);
```

When it executes, it gives me a runtime error:

> TypeError: 'stopPropagation' called on an object that does not implement interface Event.

In debug, I found that `money_am` is not a float. It is an object. But if I change my code like this:

```
var update_money = function(money_am){
    var d = {'ammount': parseFloat($('#money').val())};
    $.post("/adr/", d, load_money)
}
```

It works great. What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: What's the value of load_money?

Comment: Did you declare z as a variable earlier in the code, forgetting to declare var can give wierd behaviour?

Comment: @Paradoxis load_money is another function. I think it doesn't matter, becouse actually I have error before post. When update_money executed money_am has wrong type, and thats actually problem.

Comment: @Adrian-Forsius I didn't declare z as a variable earlier. Actually I try it now, but it didn't work too, and gives me same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data, that was passed to event handler, can be accessed by `event.data`:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nphjx80x/1/).

```
var update_money = function(event)
{
    var money_am = event.data;
    alert(money_am);
    var d = {'ammount': money_am};
    $.post("/adr/", d, load_money);
}

function load_money() { }

z = parseFloat($('#money').val());
$('#money').change(z, update_money);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the money-value is parseable by parseFloat:

You also might want to change your code to this:

```
$('#money').change(function() {
    var z = parseFloat($('#money').val());
    load_money(z);
});
```

This will allow you to get the new money value everytime #money-field is changed. Instead of always using the same value. Along with properly defining z.